# How to implement wrapper function for C sscanf() without using vsscanf()

Tags: c, variadic-functions, scanf

I want to implement a wrapper function for C `sscanf` without using `vsscanf`, because in my environment `vsscanf`() is not there only `sscanf` is there. I don't want to do a complete implementation of `sscanf` also because for that I need to consider all possible scenarios. I have seen some [samples](https://code.google.com/p/minilib-c/source/browse/trunk/stdio/scanf.c?r=8) in google, but it has not considered all scenarios.

So now I want to implement like below:

```
int my_sscanf(char * buf, char format[], ...)
{
    va_list vargs = {0};
    va_start(vargs, format);

    //some loop to get the variable aguments 
    //and call again sscanf() here.    

    va_end (vargs);
}
```

Comment: If sscanf is there why do you want to reimplement it?

Comment: I cannot call it directly in my actual project. I need to create wrapper for all system calls. so that wrapper API needs to be called in my actual project. I have implemented wrapper layer for system calls in all platforms (windows, linux, hpux, aix, vxworks, solaris, android). Now in new platform I am implementing my wrapper. All other platform I implemented with vsscanf().

Comment: `sscanf` is not a system call.

Comment: @rajaashok I'm curious – which one of those platforms does not support C99? Because C99 requires that vsscanf exists.

Comment: I am writing a wrapper for a new RTOS which has been developed inside our company with limited system calls in libc.

Answer (score 3):

Ouch!  Here's a hammer; it'll be more fun hitting yourself on the head with it.  Seriously, that's a non-trivial proposition.

You'll need a loop that scans through the format string, reading characters from the buffer when they're normal characters, remembering that spaces in the format chew up zero or more spaces in the buffer.  When you encounter a conversion specification, you'll need to create a singleton format string containing the user-supplied conversion specification plus a `%n` conversion specification.  You'll invoke:

```
int pos;
int rc = sscanf(current_pos_in_buf, manufactured_format_with_percent_n,
                appropriate_pointer_from_varargs, &pos);
```

If `rc` is not 1, you'll fail.  Otherwise, you update the current position in the buffer using the value stored in `pos`, and then repeat.  Note that scanning a conversion specification is not trivial.  Also, if there is an assignment-suppressing `*` in the specification, you'll have to expect a 0 back from `sscanf()` (and not provide the appropriate pointer from the variable args).

Answer (score 0):

Try telling your compiler to compile your code as C99. If that still doesn't work, your libc does not comply with the C99 standard – in that case, get a proper libc.

E.g. if you're using gcc, try adding `-std=c99` to the compiler command line.

Comment: yes libc is not supporting all system calls, because its constraint environment so it has limited system calls. Can we do wrapper function for sscanf by directly callsing sscanf in efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slightly simpler way to do this using the preprocessor, but it's a little hacky. Take this as an example:

```
#define my_sscanf(buf, fmt, ...) { \
    do_something(); \
    sscanf((buf), (fmt), __VA_ARGS__); \
    do_something_else(); }
```